# System.Web.HttpException: Validation of viewstate MAC failed

Tags: asp.net

Whenever I perform one particular action in my application I get this following error. 
Also:

- I only get it on first click, all my subsequent clicks work
- I only get it in IE, works fine on Google Chrome
- I don't get it on my local workstation, only on Dev/QA server
- Its a Web garden environment

**Updates**

- When I get rid of Web Garden, it still throws an error
- When I go to the server and try to run the application from there, I don't get the exception

**More Updates**

- I don't see the error with IE version 8.0.6001.18702 anymore
- IE versions where I see the error are : 8.0.7601.17514, 8.0.6001.18702IC, 7.0.5730.13
- On any version of IE with ChromeFrame 23.0.1271.97 (Official Build 171054), we do not see the issue
  Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

System.Web.HttpException: Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that  configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster. ---> System.Web.UI.ViewStateException: Invalid viewstate.

```
Client IP: XX.XXX.XX.XXXX
Port: XXXX
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; chromeframe/25.0.1364.97) AppleWebKit/537.22 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/25.0.1364.97 Safari/537.22
ViewState: 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...
```

--- End of inner exception stack trace ---

```
    at System.Web.UI.ViewStateException.ThrowError(Exception inner, String persistedState, String errorPageMessage, Boolean macValidationError)
    at System.Web.UI.ViewStateException.ThrowMacValidationError(Exception inner, String persistedState)
    at System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.Deserialize(String inputString)
    at System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.System.Web.UI.IStateFormatter.Deserialize(String serializedState)
    at System.Web.UI.Util.DeserializeWithAssert(IStateFormatter formatter, String serializedState)
    at System.Web.UI.HiddenFieldPageStatePersister.Load()
    at System.Web.UI.Page.LoadPageStateFromPersistenceMedium()
    at System.Web.UI.Page.LoadAllState()
    at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

Comment: _"I only get it in IE, works fine on Google Chrome"_ But the exception's User-Agent suggests that it was raised on chrome. http://user-agent-string.info/?Fuas=Mozilla%2F5.0+%28Windows+NT+5.1%3B+chromeframe%2F25.0.1364.97%29+AppleWebKit%2F537.22+%28KHTML%2C+like+Gecko%29+Chrome%2F25.0.1364.97+Safari%2F537.22&test=9653&action=analyze

Comment: The Application uses ChromeFrame in background to render our pages, but the page I am getting this error on does not use ChromeFrame

Comment: You keep using the term "servers" instead of "server".  Are you sure this isn't a web farm environment?

Comment: Sorry, my first time on Stack Overflow. No this isn't web Farm Environment

Comment: Is the viewstate too big ?

Comment: it works when I remote login to the server and try there. Also its only first time.